# HTML Adjust Size of Paragraph While Keeping it Centered

Tags: html, size, alignment

In my style sheet, I have

```
p {
    width: 80%;
}
```

And my paragraph has an `align` tag on it to put it in the center, but because of the style sheet, it is pushed to the left, so it is in the first 80% of the screen. How could I change this to keep it in the center?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
}
```

The `margin: 0 auto;` means that the top and bottom have zero margin and the left and right have an auto generated margin so as to centre the paragraph.

`align` is generally used for text alignment in CSS.

Check out a live demo: http://cssdesk.com/2tg9y